# Collective name for prefix and suffix of a word

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, terminology, hypernyms

Is there a term that can be used to refer to both the prefix and suffix of a word?

For example, *unenjoyable*. I'm looking for a collective word that described BOTH *un* and *able*.

Comment: If the prefix and suffix necessarily occur together, as in *en-**XXX**-en*, then together they act as a [circumfix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affix#Positional_categories_of_affixes).  Consider the circumfixed verbs *enlighten, enliven, enhearten, enharden, enripen,  enbiggen*.  In all these cases, the **XXX** is an adjective, and applying this particular circumfix to said adjective produces a verb that bestows that quality on something.

Comment: not sure about a single word, but I believe an apt phrase would be the "grammarians' crucifix"!

Comment: The opening sentence of the Wikipedia article on [*prefix*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix): "A prefix is an [affix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affix) which is placed before the stem of a word.". And the very first sentence of the Wikipedia article on [*suffix*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix): "In linguistics, a suffix [...] is an [affix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affix) which is placed after the stem of a word.".

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think the word you are looking for is [affix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affix), though that also includes "-fixes" other than just "suffix" and "prefix".

> [Noun: affix (plural affixes)](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/affix)
>
> (linguistics) A bound morpheme added to a word’s stem; formerly applied only to suffixes (also called postfixes), the term as now used comprises prefixes, suffixes, infixes, circumfixes, and suprafixes.

Answer (score 11):

I believe you are looking for "affix"

noun
Grammar

noun: affix; plural noun: affixes

/ˈæˌfɪks/

1. an additional element placed at the beginning or end of a root, stem, or word,
   or in the body of a word, to modify its meaning.

Comment: Ah, beat me too it. Simultaneous answering :-)

Comment: Where is this quote from? *Always* cite your sources. Moderators are instructed to delete on sight anything that's not properly attributed.

Answer (score 1):

Like the other answers mentioned, the general word referring to prefixes, suffixes and similar, is *affix*. However, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infix) also mentions *adfix* as joint name for prefixes and suffixes but **not** any other kind of affix:

> It [infix] contrasts with adfix, a rare term for an affix attached to
>   the end of a stem, such as a prefix or suffix.

See the [definition of *adfix* in Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/adfix).